# Annotation endpoint Location for JAX-WS

Tags: spring, annotations, jax-ws, cxf

does exist a specific annotation to define the address of the endpoint.
In fact, I want to remove the attribute address in the SPring file and move the annotation directly in the impl. class.

**Current:**

> jaxws:endpoint id="dataManagerEndPoint" implementor="#dataManagerService" address="/datamanager/v1.0"

@WebService
public interface DataManagerService

**I would like to change to (if possible) ...**

> jaxws:endpoint id="dataManagerEndPoint" implementor="#dataManagerService"

@WebService
@EndPointAddress ("/datamanager/v1.0")
public interface DataManagerService

Many thanks, in advance,
Christophe P.

Answer (score 0):

```
@WebService(portName = "PortTypeName", serviceName = "ServiceName", targetNamespace = "http://www.namespace.com", wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdlname.wsdl", endpointInterface = "com.package.service.PortTypeName")
```